# How to return a json response in a function and compare it?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

So basically I'm getting a "return outside function" error when I execute the code.

What I would like to achieve is to make a function that gets a JSON response from an API then I could compare that response with a string to insert some text if they are identical.

here is my code.

```
def res():
  api = "http://football-api.com/api/?Action=competitions&APIKey=aade7b79-af8b-9908-ad990d651a08&comp_id=1204"
  respobj = requests.get(api)
  adict = respobj.json()
  theresponse = adic['ERROR'] 
return theresponse

if(res()) == "no matches found today":
   output.insert(END, "There no premier leauge matches today")
else:
 # Grab todays matches and scores from the API
   output.insert(END, "  ")
```

And this is the api response that i'm trying to get the Object "ERROR" from

```
{
  "APIVersion": 1,
  "APIRequestsRemaining": 983,
  "DeveloperAuthentication": "TRUE",
  "Action": "today",
  "Params": {
    "Action": "today",
    "APIKey": "aade7b79-af8b-9908-ad990d651a08",
    "comp_id": "1204"
  },
  "ComputationTime": 0.079131126403809,
  "IP": "**********",
  "ERROR": "no matches found today",
  "ServerName": "Football-API",
  "ServerAddress": "http://football-api.com/api"
}
```

Comment: fix the indentation pls... and return outside function likely means that you have non-indented return in your code...

Comment: Any resource i can you use to figure out how should I properly indent my code? I'm just a beginner here.

Comment: this one may help you: http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html but other than that just google around, there is a lot of resource covering the basics. would recommend doing some tutorials if you're completely new to it.

Comment: I fixed the indentation, but now the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: first step you need is urllib parse by url.. store it in var then use json.loads and access like var['ERROR']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def res(self):
    request_url = "http://football-api.com/api/?Action=competitions&APIKey=aade7b79-af8b-9908-ad990d651a08&comp_id=1204"

    parse_url = urllib.urlopen(request_url).read()

    raw_data = json.dumps(parse_url)
    json_data = json.loads(raw_data)

if (json_data['ERROR']):
    //do something
```

This is simple approach to fetch data from an API. according to your need, you can always modify code!